# How to get around matching Boost Variant return types?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

[**Linked Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167067/boost-variant-type-collision)

Suppose we have:

```
boost::variant<nil, std::string, string_struct>
```

And,

```
struct string_struct
{
   string_struct(std::string const& name = "") : name(name) {}
   std::string name;
}
```

Is there some way to prevent the compiler from incorrectly inferring the wrong boost variant type?

More theoretically, if we had a

```
boost::variant<std::string, std::string>
```

I don't think it would compile. The first example would, however. The problem is, how do we guarantee no collision of return types? Specifically, when used as part of a parser, there are innumerable instances where we would desire the first example. So...

Comment: Why not just do `var = string_struct(string_param);` if you know you want to initialize a `string_struct` rather than a `string`

Comment: Additionally, you can make the constructor `explicit`, and remove the implicit conversion from `const std::string&`.

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess my comment doesn't address the issue of trying to initialize the string variant...  Making the constructor explicit will solve that, making my first comment a necessity rather than just a suggestion.

Comment: Ok, bear with me. I'm not sure I follow. In this particular case, I **want** the member 'name' to be of type std::string. Additionally, I would like the parameter string_struct takes to be of type std:string const&.

Answer (score 1):

This code is untested, but I am confident this will solve your problem.

```
    struct string_struct
    {
        explicit string_struct(const std::string & s):name(s){}
    };

    typedef boost::variant<nil, std::string, string_struct> var_t;

    var_t v1 = std::string("Hello");
    var_t v2 = string_struct("Hello");
```

`var1` will be unambiguously initialized to hold a string because to construct a `string_struct` you have to call its constructor explicitly.  `var2` will, of course, be initialized to hold a string_struct because that's what you passed to the variant.

**EDIT**

<s>Okay, there's a lot of type information missing about the rule(s) and struct(s) you added so I'm going to go ahead and say that those should be added to your question.</s> I finally found the definitions in your previous question.

Disregarding that for the moment, my best guess as of right now for what you can do is to have the rule for an identifier return an actual identifier instead of a string (it is really confusing to have an identifier type and an identifier rule btw, but I realize that you're not the one who did that).

**EDIT 2**

Rather than post another comment, I'll put it here:

You have `qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), skipper<Iterator> > identifier;`, which declares the return type of this rule as being `std::string`.  Change that to `qi::rule<Iterator, identifier(), skipper<Iterator> > identifier;`, which declares the return type of the rule to be an `identifier`.  Note the change from `std::string` to `identifier`.  Let me know if this helps you or if you have already done that.

Comment: So, the problem with that is that I require string_struct to retain it's data member 'name'.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, in your example your `string_struct` holds a copy of the string used to construct it and so does my example.  I'm not sure what it is you want to be able to do if not this...

Comment: where does 'name' come from in your example?

Comment: The major issue is that I don't know at compile time when an instance of var_t will be created. I realize that instantiating it explicitly solves the problem, but I don't have that luxury.

Comment: If you want to understand the context within which I am working ,check out my previous question on Stack.

Comment: @Dylan_Larkin If, at the time of creation of the variant, you don't know whether your string represents a `string` or a `string_struct` then you have a fundamental ambiguity that needs to be fixed.  I will check your previous question, if you feel the context is important then you should include a link to it in your question.

Comment: Looking at your previous question, can't you disambiguate all of this by introducing a `string_literal` and `identifier` class, and making the parsers return these, so no std::string confusion is involved?

Comment: @Dylan_Larkin I agree with melak47. Basically defining custom types for everything (even if they only hold one parameter) makes everything easier and more self-documenting in the case of tag dispatching (making use of the overload resolution in the way you are)

Comment: Yes, that was going to be my approach. I was hoping there might be something more simple, first.

Comment: So, the problem is now I initialization is ambiguous. The compiler still can't tell the difference between string_literal and identifier, even when I wrap it with a struct.

Comment: @GuyGreer, since you've looked at my previous post, here is another question perhaps you could answer. Is there a way to define the identifier's production rule to say explicitly that it is not the same as a string_literal? Maybe this will solve the fundamental problem that is clearly inherent in my approach (but thank you for noticing that as provided, the mini_c tutorial sort of pigeonholes me into this).

Comment: @Dylan_Larkin Just `qi::rule<Iterator, identifier(), skipper<Iterator> >`.  That tells the library that you want this rule to return an `identifier` object.

Comment: It's already defined that way, so I suppose that isn't the problem. so I've wrapped 'string_literal' in a struct, but now the compiler has flipped it's confusion to the opposite scenario. This is starting to feel hopeless. I still can't figure out a suitable way to differentiate the two.

Comment: @Dylan_Larkin When I looked at the link for the `identifier` it was defined as `qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), skipper<Iterator> >` which tells the library that this rule returns a string.  This is why this is a problem, the `quoted_string` and `identifier` rules are both returning `std::string` in their rules and so the variant can't tell which you want to initialize.

Comment: Right, hence the title of my question. This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: @GuyGreer, so there isn't a quick way around this?